# POSTGRESQL Queries using Python

Tags: python, postgresql

I am trying to access tables from a database using python. There was some code on the website: https://rnacentral.org/help/public-database

```
import psycopg2.extras


def main():
    conn_string = "host='hh-pgsql-public.ebi.ac.uk' dbname='pfmegrnargs' user='reader' password='NWDMCE5xdipIjRrp'"
    conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
    cursor = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)`

    # retrieve a list of RNAcentral databases
    query = "SELECT * FROM rnc_database"

    cursor.execute(query)
    for row in cursor:
        print(row)`
```

When i run this code, i get back a list of databases:
[image]

I want to access tables from one of these databases but I don't know what the schema for those tables are or what the values in each list returned represents. I have been looking at 'postgresql to python' resources but all of them are about accessing tables when you know the name of the tables and the columns within.... Is there code for how I can access the table names from the database?

Thank You

Edit: sorry, i thought i linked the website before

Comment: More information is needed, add answers to your question: 1) What website did the code come from? 2) What are the actual fields that `*` expands to?

Comment: Alright, change `psycopg2.extras.DictCursor` to `psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor` nd you will get the field names. And the Website I'm guessing is [Postgres db](https://rnacentral.org/help/public-database). At the top of that page is schema diagram for that database that shows the tables and below that the main tables to look at. `rnc_database` is just a table in the database. Your best bet would be to use this: `psql postgres://reader:NWDMCE5xdipIjRrp@hh-pgsql-public.ebi.ac.uk:5432/pfmegrnargs` to connect directly to the database and look around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dataset you want to use has schema diagram here https://rnacentral.org/help/public-database

For general purpose I would use something like https://dbeaver.io/ tool it will show you all the schemas in the db and tables inside the schema and so forth. The DBeaver settings to connect to your db would look like this [image]

If you want to keep using python script to explore the db this sql query

```
SELECT *
FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables
WHERE schemaname != 'pg_catalog' AND 
    schemaname != 'information_schema';
```

Should help you.